# proper version of pyhook installed but fails to run the code

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyhook

I am using python 2.7.13 32 bit, have installed 'pyHook-1.5.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl' proper version pyhook.

I am running this below code:

```
import pyhook

def fun():
print "Do something"

#create pyhk class instance
hot = pyhk.pyhk()

#add hotkey
hot.addHotkey(['Ctrl', 'Alt','7'],fun)

#start looking for hotkey.
hot.start()
```

But fails to run the code giving below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "take.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyhook
ImportError: No module named pyhook
```

Just to check i have installed it below is output when i do pip install

```
pip install pyHook
Requirement already satisfied: pyHook in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
```

Comment: Could you have more than one version of Python installed?

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you seems to be importing `pyhook`, however, this is case sensitive, and should be `pyHook`

Comment: i had tried that earlier i got this error.   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "take.py", line 7, in <module>
    hot = pyhk.pyhk()
NameError: name 'pyhk' is not defined

Comment: Well this is another problem, you're trying to use pyhk, not pyhook. Pyhook is just a dependency for pyhk. run `pip install pyhk` and it should work

Comment: 'pip install pyhk
Collecting pyhk
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhk (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyhk'

Comment: Sorry, pyhk is not distributed via pip. you will have to fetch the file `pyhk.py`from this link, and put it in the same folder as your source : https://github.com/schurpf/pyhk

Comment: Downloaded pyhk.py from git, I tried placing it source folder of my actual file and ran not working or should it be C:/python27/Lib or somewhere else

Comment: When i run placing pyhk.py ins source and running i get this error as below: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "take.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyhk
  File "C:\Users\vsukhen\Desktop\pyhk.py", line 7
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Wait, how did you download the file ? it seems you downloaded the webpage ... This is line 7 of pyhk.py : # Extends pyhook to have normal hotkey functionality like autohotkey (AHK) scripts.

This is line 7 of the webpage : <!DOCTYPE html>

You did not download the file. You downloaded the webpage ...

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code as: 'import pyhook' to 'import pyHook'. Also try: 'import pyhk'

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "take.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyhk
ImportError: No module named pyhk'

Comment: i tried already pyHook and import pyhk getting this above error.

Comment: Tried pip install?

Comment: https://github.com/schurpf/pyhk . download .py file from here and import pyhk. It should work